# How do I add class from array to n divs using .each function?

Tags: jquery, html, each

Basically what I'm trying to do is this

```
var arr = ["red","green","blue"];
$('.box').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass(Array Value Here)
});
```

and I want the result to be like this.

```
<div class"box red"></div>
<div class"box green"></div>
<div class"box blue"></div>
<div class"box red"></div>
<div class"box green"></div>
<div class"box blue"></div>
<div class"box red"></div>
<div class"box green"></div>
<div class"box blue"></div>
```

How can I do that?
The number of total divs are unknown.

Comment: You are highly encouraged to accept someone's answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Modulo [`%`] is your friend:

```
var colours = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];
$('.box').each(function(index, element) {
  $(element).addClass(colours[index % colours.length]);
});
```

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gRNT4/1/).

Comment: It does work. I was in the process of writing this same answer: http://jsbin.com/nojipowo/2/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: it works Thanks!!
From where can I learn about this % ?
if you don't mind...Could you explain how this works?

Comment: It returns the remainder of two numbers.

Comment: @user3407278 [wiki is your friend](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

Answer (score 2):

```
var arr = ['red', 'green', 'blue'],
i = 0,
len = arr.length;

$('.box').each(function(index, box) {
  console.log(box);
  $(box).addClass(arr[i]);
  ++i;
  if (i === len) {
    i = 0;
  }
});
```

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

```
     var arr = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];
      $('.box').each(function(i,o) {
         $(this).addClass(arr[i%arr.length]);
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just styling you can avoid the JS all together by using `:nth-child`.

```
.box:nth-child(3n + 1) {
  color: red;
}

.box:nth-child(3n + 2) {
  color: green;
}

.box:nth-child(3n + 3) {
  color: blue;
}
```